# How to join two tables with multiple rows in the one table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Let's say I have:

```
USERS:
userid | name
1      | John
2      | Jack

HITS:
id | userid | time
1  | 1      | 50
2  | 1      | 51
3  | 2      | 52
4  | 1      | 53
5  | 2      | 54
6  | 2      | 55
```

I need to end up with a structure like this:

```
array() {
  [user 1] {
    hit 1 => 50
    hit 2 => 51
    hit 4 => 53
  }
  [user 2] {
    hit 3 => 52
    hit 5 => 54
    hit 6 => 55
  }
}
```

The worst possible way to do this is to:

1. Select * users
2. Select all hits for each users

Is there a way to get a result as one single query without going through each like this?

Comment: Yes, it's a very simple join. I will like to see the code you have tried.

Comment: I think I was unclear, that's why it was simple. I want to know how to end up with ONE USER, and each hit beneath that as part of one query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **Left Outer Join**, Retrieve All records from **left table(main)** and other matching from **right table**.

```
select 
users.userid,  
h.time 
from  
users  
    left outer join hits h   
    on(  
      users.userid = h.userid
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a `JOIN` for this.

```
SELECT * FROM users
INNER JOIN hits on users.id = hits.user_id
```

Your result would come through as a flat array but you can easily loop through and format your array accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

the sql statement you need is simply using `INNER JOIN` (*or LEFT JOIN if ou want to return records even a certain user has no matching record on table hits*)

```
SELECT  a.*, b.time
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN hits b
            ON a.userid = b.userid
```

the result of the query is a single dimensional array so you need to format the result in the application level.

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM users
LEFT JOIN hits on users.id = hits.user_id
```

Comment: Mind adding a little text explanation to your code-only answer?